# How can convert string to date with mongo aggregation not working always return null?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

In a collection, I store this kind of document

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "created_at" : "2021-11-01",
    ...
}.
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "created_at" : "2021-12-01",
    ...
}
```

I would like to convert created_at to date and i use this method

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{ created_at:{$dateFromString:{dateString:'$created_at'}}}}
])
```

---

but the result alwas null
Anybody have solution to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `$dateFromString` operator will assume that the string is in `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ`.

If not, which is the case in your scenario, you have to manually enter the format in which you want MongoDB to parse the string using the `format` option.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      created_at: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$created_at",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, I applied this change but nothing change

Comment: It is working fine in my local. Check the MongoDB playground results here.  https://mongoplayground.net/p/HsrJFhJ-sDc

Comment: thanks a lot, it is working for me thanks